# TypeError: morphSearch.querySelector(...) is null

Tags: javascript, typeerror, selectors-api

Can anyone resolve my problem with my code ( i just discovered it from debug mode )

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var morphSearch = document.getElementById( 'morphsearch' ),
            input = morphSearch.querySelector( 'input.morphsearch-input' ),
            ctrlClose = morphSearch.querySelector( 'span.morphsearch-close'),
        // ...
</script>
```

This is not all of the code that I have, it's long so I just put the first lines of it.

In debug mode I get this error :

> TypeError: morphSearch.querySelector(...) is null

Here is the generated markup: http://pastebin.com/P6tfvcZS

Is there a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Would probably help to provide the HTML and a bit more code. Would need to verify an element exists with the id = morphsearch.

Comment: `.querySelector()` returns `null` if the element does not exist (at least the `document.querySelector()` works so)

Comment: dear @WhiteHat 
this is my php page 
http://pastebin.com/P6tfvcZS

Comment: What does the actual HTML look like? Not the PHP but the output which is send to and interpreted by the browser.

Comment: @Andreas this is how it looks like on HTML !

http://pastebin.com/P6tfvcZS

thank you so much for yous assistance

Comment: The script should work and the HTML/Javascript in the pastebin link does not throw the mentioned error. Instead it fails on `morphSearch.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click'` because there is no `button` in the markup. If this is fixed then there is still the missing `classie`. If this will also be fixed the script should work as intended. http://jsfiddle.net/bnjwjpsL/

Answer (score 0):

found this...

```
var offsets = morphsearch.getBoundingClientRect();
```

morphSearch is the wrong case, I'm thinking it should be...

```
var offsets = morphSearch.getBoundingClientRect();
```

I also separated your `var` statements. The last one looked like this...

```
isOpen = isAnimating = false,
```

I don't *think* that's valid, try it like this.

```
  var morphSearch = document.getElementById( 'morphsearch' );
  var input = morphSearch.querySelector( 'input.morphsearch-input' );
  var ctrlClose = morphSearch.querySelector( 'span.morphsearch-close' );
  var isOpen = false;
  var isAnimating = false;
```

Those `querySelector`'s appear to be working...

Actually, a side from the above, I think I found the only `querySelector` that wasn't working.

Try changing this...

```
morphSearch.querySelector( 'button[type="submit"]' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); } );
```

To...

```
morphSearch.querySelector( 'input.morphsearch-submit' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); } );
```

All that should do it.

Comment: i tried your advice but still same error ! ( i use this code on my wordpress theme )